# InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature - Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions

I have HTTP Triggred Functions.

I'm using Postman to Post to send json with https://.azurewebsites.net/api/?code=

I'm getting error 500 with Postman. I'm using default host key.

Azure Function Monitor error is:

```
Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid 
signature. TrackingId:11d500b8-47e4-419f-8c6b-4e789e101b9a, SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, 
Timestamp:2020-04-27T09:51:22.
```

Comment: So you face this problem with using the original template? If not face this error when using template, can you provide the code of your function?

Comment: Did you start any verification method for the function on azure? Can you clearly describe your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from `Authentication / Authorization`:

[image]

But to solve your problem, you need to offer more information.

Comment: "Anonymous access is enabled on the App Service app. Users will not be prompted for login." App Service Authentication=Off